# How do I insert this emoji in Google App Scipt?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, unicode, emoji

So I have a Google App Script which sends out email but it's giving me these � .
The code is as follows, please help me out !! :

> ```
> <base target="_top">   </head>   <body>
> <p>Hey <?= meta.name ?>!</p>
> <p>Congratulations! You made it!      </p>
> ```

The code above is another html file in the Google App Script and I am sure I amusing MailApp and not something else.

Comment: Is it `GmailApp` or `MailApp`? Show your code

Comment: Try this `<p>Congratulations! You made it! &#127881; &#127881; &#127881; &#127881;</p>`